# How I can find closest date by single request using pymongo? Date should be closest to Current Date

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Dataset :

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"61e038a052124accf41cb5e4"},"event_date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1642204800000"}},
"name":"UFC Fight Night","event_url":"https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/events/82805-ufc-fight-night","location":"Las Vegas, NV"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"61e038a252124accf41cb5e5"},"event_date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1642809600000"}},"name":"UFC 270","event_url":"https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/events/82993-ufc-270","location":"Anaheim, CA"}
{"_id":{"$oid":"61e038a252124accf41cb5e6"},"event_date":{"$date":{"$numberLong":"1644019200000"}},"name":"UFC Fight Night","event_url":"https://www.tapology.com/fightcenter/events/83125-ufc-fight-night","location":"Las Vegas, NV"}
```

I'm using python, and that means I have no way to use $commands in my code for Mongo DB to find collection I need. Question is how can find object which should have datetime value closest to current date.  As I understand I have to use python's datetime.now() to set current date and compare it ($currentDate doesn't work for Python). But but in order to compare values I have to deserialize the object and this looks very heavy. By default Mongo uses ISO datetime type.
Can you help me? At least direction to put me on a right way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution with an aggregate

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "dateDiff": {
        "$abs": {
          "$subtract": [
            "$event_date",
            {
              "$literal": new Date()
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "dateDiff": 1
    }
  }
])
```

- I use `$subtract` to have a difference between `event_date` and today.
- `$abs` is to have the absolute value. To have the closest in the future or in the past.
- And then we just have to sort by `dateDiff`

In your code you have to replace `new Date()`

Try it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KSAlTuGRPTx)

Comment: what you mean by replace with new Date(), sorry?

Comment: "new Date()" here is the way to have the current date in MongoDB, You have to replace it with the python equivalent. As you mention you can use "datetime"

Comment: Ah I see, thank you very much Alexis :)